# Посчитать сколько раз слово встречается в тексте

Tags: алгоритм, поиск, текст, nlp

Хотелось бы узнать реально ли это реализовать вот так: слова в единственном и множественном числе распознавать как одно и то же слово. Да, тексты на английском. Так что глаголы в разных временах тоже нужно считать одним и тем же словом.

Ну типа вот глагол  drink, drank, drunk в трёх временах везде по-разному пишется.

Может кто-то знает где есть готовые алгоритмы для такого дела? Или где что-то подобное реализовано, можно подсмотреть

Comment: Естественный язык — это сплошные исключения, так что строить алгоритм, видимо, придется на таблицах: все эти слова считать одним, эти — другим и т.д. Ну, а для развлечения — взгляните [это](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IlzpcpnFAPfJkiFFVyez3a3U7knV8HWq/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: А вот, например, во фразе _"The drunk drunk his drink and got drunk"_ сколько каких слов должно получиться?

Comment: А в “ Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo”  https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo

Answer (score 3):

Как уже написали в комментариях, задача не такая простая. Поскольку ЯП был не обозначен, приведу варианты для `Python`. Основная `NLP` (natural language processing) библиотека для него это, пожалуй, [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/), хотя есть и другие, как на основе `NLTK`, так и самостоятельные.

Что нужно вам из всего `NLP`:

- `POS tagging` (POS = part of speech)
- `lemmatization`

Лемматизация делает именно то, что вам нужно - приводит слова в нормальную форму. Но ей для работы нужно знать, что вы подали на вход - глагол или существительное, как уже упомянули в комментариях. И тут действительно проблема, можно применить POS-tagger для определения части речи, но если его применять к отдельным словам, он не сможет разобрать, где существительное, а где глагол и выберет просто то, что чаще встречается в текстах по статистике. Для того, чтобы учитывать контекст нужны уже сложные модели на основе нейросетей, которые анализируют текст целиком. Такие модели тоже есть, но это уже "тяжёлая артиллерия", думаю, вам нужно начать всё же с чего-то попроще.